# GPU/CUDA function for bilateral filter in OpenCV 3

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, filter, gpu, opencv3.0

First of all, sorry if I am asking something very obvious, but after a long search, I haven't found anything.

I am porting an old project from OpenCV 2 to OpenCV 3, but I don't know how to port `cv::gpu::bilateralFilter`. For performance purposes, I need to use a gpu bilateral filter function, but I cannot see anything similar. For the moment I am using `cv::bilateralFilter`, but I am afraid this is not using gpu.

Also, I found `cv::cuda::bilateralFilter` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d05/group__cudaimgproc.html), but it is not something callable from the last version in the OpenCV repository code (with CUDA enabled).

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit 1: Diving in the source code, I have found that, actually, `cv::cuda::bilateralFilter` is callable if I include `#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"`even when this doesn't appear in the documentation. The problem now is that I get a link error in Visual Studio 2015 that I don't understand :/

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cuda::bilateralFilter(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,float,float,int,class cv::cuda::Stream &)" (?bilateralFilter@cuda@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@2@AEBV_OutputArray@2@HMMHAEAVStream@12@@Z)
```

Comment: were you capable of using it? Sorry for late post

Comment: mmm No, sorry :(